# Get DateTime value from excel cell with C#

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core

I'm trying to get `DateTime` value from an uploaded excel file to the databse. This is what I have:

```
 DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
 if(worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value != null){//if cell is not empty
     date = worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value.ToString().Trim();//doesn't work b/c not the same type
     //I also tried:
     //date = DateTime.FromOAdDate(worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value)
 }
```

The above expects a type `double` for `FromOADate`. I'm not sure how to get the cell value to convert to type `double`.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is a `double` expected? Also, what is the value of the `cell`? The issue looks like you're trying to assign a `string` to a `DateTime` type, which doesn't work. Use `DateTime.TryParse()` or `DateTime.TryParseExact()`, depending on what the value in the cell looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the string to `Datetime.`

```
date = DateTime.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value.ToString());
```

you can also use the DateTime.TryParse method to make sure you get a value and not an exception.

```
DateTime.TryParse(worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value.ToString(), out date)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks a lot